# iOS Enterprise Program vs Volume Purchase Program

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise, b2b, apple-vpp

Our company developed its own products and we want to distribute it to our clients ( other companies ) personnels. We have already have an iOS Company Account ( similar to Individual Account but with DUNS number registered ) . However our clients may don’t want to see their specific apps on the market; so I had to distribute it in a different way. After some research I come up with two solutions;

1. iOS Enterprise Program
2. Custom B2B Applications ( downloading by Volume Purchase Program )

a) I know that Enterprise Program applications should be downloaded only by the employees of the company that they are working. If I bought this program, distribute my apps to a server with SSL cert. how apple is going to check my downloads ? Since devices UDID’s for distributing not required to be registered and the app can be downloaded by unlimited devices, how is it going to be the validation process ?

b) I tried to distribute an app for custom b2b but I could’t see an option under the prices segment. I create a new app under iTunes Connect and filled all the description parts. I choose free option under prices tab and even if my location is in Turkey ( since I verified the conditions for creating the app ) I couldn’t see a checkbox “Custom B2B App” ?  What am I missing ?

[image: screenshot]

If I have to sign up for VPP (Volume Purchase Program) to distribute apps , should other companies have to sign up this program also to make their employees use our app ? Even if I have to sign up VPP on the page ( https://deploy.apple.com/qforms/open/register/enroll1/avs?program=vpp ) ; they want me to use firm email address not the one that I used for developing apps (my iOS Company Account registered one). So when I will going to distribute apps, how it will going to understood that I had a VPP registered and add a checkbox for me ?

My example scenario is like;

- Company XYZ (mine) -> developed apps A & B.
- Company ABC personnels want to use app A & B for company ABC specific versions.
- Company DEF personnels want to use app A & B for company DEF specific versions.

**Note:** Money is not an issue for us to buy an Enterprise Program and an SSL certificate etc if we will do it for once. But if we have to buy it for every single one of the company (ABC,DEF,..) it would be a problem.

- What is the best option to do it ?
- If it's option b ( Custom b2b ) then how successfully I can make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS**

a) I know that Enterprise Program applications should be downloaded only by the employees of the company that they are working. If I bought this program, distribute my apps to a server with SSL cert. how apple is going to check my downloads ? Since devices UDID’s for distributing not required to be registered and the app can be downloaded by unlimited devices, how is it going to be the validation process ?

==> NO, Apple does not track/check your download. You can provide directly to your customer by website download and simple provide and ipa to download with itunes.

b) I tried to distribute an app for custom b2b but I could’t see an option under the prices segment. I create a new app under iTunes Connect and filled all the description parts. I choose free option under prices tab and even if my location is in Turkey ( since I verified the conditions for creating the app ) I couldn’t see a checkbox “Custom B2B App” ? What am I missing ?

==> As per my knowledge. You should go with the iOS Enterprise program. It is suitable with your requirement.

**Note:** Money is not an issue for us to buy an Enterprise Program and an SSL certificate etc if we will do it for once. But if we have to buy it for every single one of the company (ABC,DEF,..) it would be a problem.

**ANSWER**

You can create multiple builds in an single enterprise program. You can create multiple identifiers or certificated to handle multiple builds.

What is the best option to do it ?

==> Option a is the best.